# Reuse mocked function with different return values

Tags: jestjs, nestjs, nestjs-typeorm

Currently trying to create some unit tests for a service but I'm running into a problem where my service has several functions that call the same typeorm function, notably `getRawMany()`, and as a result one test will pass, but any other test fails to run correctly because the data that's been mocked isn't what I'm expecting.

the mock I've created is similar to the following:

```
const testOneData = ["one", "two", "three"]
const testTwoData = ["five", "ten", "fifteen", "twenty"]
const testThreeData = ["cat", "dog", "bear", "cougar"]

export const MockTestRepository = () => ({
  find: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  createQueryBuilder: jest.fn(() => ({
    select: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    distinctOn: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    getRawMany: jest
    .fn()
    .mockReturnValue(testOneData)
    .mockReturnValueOnce(testTwoData)
    .mockReturnValueOnce(testThreeData),
    leftJoinAndSelect: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    where: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    getMany: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(testOneData),
  })),
});
```

```
  it("should return collection of regions", async () => {
    //-- arrange
    const _agency = "cos";

    //-- act
    const results = await service.getRegionsByAgency(_agency)

    //-- assert
    expect(results).not.toBe(null);
    expect(results.length).not.toBe(0);
    expect(results.length).toBe(8);
  });

  it("should return collection of zones", async () => {
    //-- arrange
    const _agency = "cos";

    //-- act
    const results = await service.getZonesByAgency(_agency)

    //-- assert
    expect(results).not.toBe(null);
    expect(results.length).not.toBe(0);
    expect(results.length).toBe(9);
  });

  it("should return collection of communities", async () => {
    //-- arrange
    const _agency = "cos";

    //-- act
    const results = await service.getCommunitiesByAgency(_agency)

    //-- assert
    expect(results).not.toBe(null);
    expect(results.length).not.toBe(0);
    expect(results.length).toBe(11);
  });
```

Now I think I know why this is behaving the way it is becuase in my describe I have a `beforeEach` which as I understand things, resets the mock, so in a way it makes sense that in my mock any time `getRawMany()` is called it will only use `testOneData`, but what I want is reuse that mock so that the next time that function is called, it uses the `testTwoData` and `testThreeData` and the only way I see that happening is if I create three different mocks and create three different describe blocks with a single test in each or to create one test that tests all three service functions which seems like the wrong thing to do.

Is there a way that I can achieve this or will I have to split my tests into separate describes, or one single test?